# Can you update CHANGE_RETENTION on single table?

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have change tracking enabled on the database level with a retention period of 5 days. Is it possible to update a single table to 10 days?

If not what is the query to update the db. Microsoft doco gives this example:

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON  
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)
```

If I run this the query breaks at line 2 since change tracking is already on

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not able to alter `CHANGE_RETENTION` property directly. Before re-enable `CHANGE_RETENTION` property for the database, we need to disable `CHANGE_RETENTION` for the tables which have been enabled. Disable and enable commands can refer  [Enable and Disable Change Tracking (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

1. Disable them:

```sql
ALTER TABLE <table1>
DISABLE CHANGE_TRACKING

ALTER TABLE <table2>
DISABLE CHANGE_TRACKING
...

ALTER DATABASE <DBName>
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = OFF
```

2. Then enable them:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE <DBName>
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 10 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)

ALTER TABLE <table1>
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING

ALTER TABLE <table2>
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING
...
```